# Eclipse search results - filename not showing

Tags: php, eclipse, search

I've searched/googled/binged for this and I seem to be the only developer on the planet with this issue, I've been living with it for years but it's impacting my productivity.

If I File Search on eclipse, 3.7.2 on Centos, (but this happens on all my installations, all OS) with a relatively large result set (50+ files), the tree displays fine, but the file names aren't showing.  (PHP and other perspectives).

Normally I see the triangle arrow, the symbol (file/dir) and the line number arrow plus filename.

When the result set is large I get everything except the filename...  If I click the arrows they open the correct file/line, and the properties of the elements (files, dirs etc) show fine when right clicked.

Clicking View Error Log in the Installation details gives no response, but otherwise the IDE works fine.

Any clues where to look to debug/fix would be appreciated.

Here's a screen shot...
[image: Empty results]

Comment: I think screen shot would help explain what you're seeing; I, for one, can't picture what you're describing.

Comment: I can't actually post an image but each line has the expected arrow and image but it is blank afterwards.  So instead of "v (image) (arrow) line number filename"  u only see "v (image) (arrow)"

Comment: I had this problem, all I had to do was switch to List View and then back to Tree View and it snapped back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same issue. the only way for me to get around with that is to let eclipse list with list perspective not as tree structure. There is an option in the search pannel let you to specify that.

Update: 
found a solution. I guess there are some build files that has uncomfortable contents in, so eclipse is not happy when searching through these. Change your search working set to exclude those files, then you should be good to go. You can find which files are causing trouble by using the 'list view perspective' I described above.